# ADBannerView Confusion (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad, adbannerview

I've searched and searched and searched and searched for clarification on how to do this, but I still don't know how to do this correctly.

**My predicament and what I want my result to be:**

I have an `ADBannerView` added to my storyboard, and the variable name where I implement it is `bannerView`. I'm making an option to *disable* ads in the game. If ads are disabled, then ads shouldn't even load. If I'm correct, then the delegate's `bannerViewWillLoadWithAd:` method shouldn't be called, nor should the `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` method. I use this code, enclosed in an "if" statement, to remove the `ADBannerView` from the view controller:

```
[bannerView removeFromSuperview];
[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:NO];
```

And then my delegate methods look like this (my delegate is my game scene, and the view controller is referenced by a property of said scene `viewController1`):

```
-(BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave {
    NSLog(@"banner view action will begin.");
    self.paused = YES;
    return YES;
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"Ad loaded.");
}

-(void)bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"Ad Banner will load ad.");
    if (// ads are disabled) {
        viewController1.canDisplayBannerAds = NO;
        [banner removeFromSuperview]; 
        NSLog(@"Banner shouldn't load");
    }
}

-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    NSLog(@"Ad Banner action did finish");
    self.paused = NO;
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Ad banner view failed to load. Details about the error: %@", error.debugDescription);
    banner.hidden = YES;
}
```

The code works, but I end up getting errors and odd happenings in the logs, which typically include "service session terminated" when ads are supposed to show and ads loading when they're not supposed to. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're using `[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES]` in addition to creating your own `ADBannerView`. You need to use one or the other. `[self setCanDisplayBannerAds:YES]` is actually creating an `ADBannerView` for you in addition to the one **you** are creating.

To remove the ads you should not be waiting until an ad loads to deal with hiding them. You should check once at the launch of your application and deal with it then. If you decide to use `setCanDisplayBannerAds` its quite simple:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (disableAds) {
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = NO;
    }
}
```

If you decide to use your own implemented `ADBannerView` your code may look more like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (disableAds) {
        banner.hidden = YES;
        banner.delegate = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: I never set `canDisplayBannerAds` to `YES`. However, I can remove where it sets `canDisplayBannerAds` to `NO`.

Comment: Sorry @DDPWNAGE, I assumed you were setting `canDisplayBannerAds` as you showed you were setting it to `NO`. There's no need to set it to `NO` if you're not setting it to `YES`. Simply remove `canDisplayBannerAds` and follow the second example I've provided.

Comment: I will when I get the chance. I didn't know `canDisplayBannerAds` would make a second banner view on the bottom of the screen. How would one get properties of _that_ banner view (like the delegate, the frame, etc.)?

Comment: @DDPWNAGE from my experience it is not possible. You could check your `view` to see if it contains an `ADBannerView` or not and respond accordingly, but If you want complete and easy control implement your own `ADBannerView` like you have done already.

Comment: alright. I was curious about that. It's weird for me to create a banner view with no delegate object. I'm going to implement my own banner view.